# How to use for loop to loop this without so many line for 5 groups?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sequence

Basically Group 1 is the average of 1st, 6th, 11th of the data. Group 2 is the average of 2nd, 7th, 12th of the data, same goes to group 3,4, and 5.
There are some sequence in there which i think able to use for loop to get the result instead of this messy method. How should I do it by using the for loop?

The below coding is the one that I had tried

```
x <- c(3,41,435,534,222,234,1,2,5,2,5,77,433,22,44)

Group1 <- (x[1] + x[6] + x[11])/3
Group2 <- (x[2] + x[7] + x[12])/3
Group3 <- (x[3] + x[8] + x[13])/3
Group4 <- (x[4] + x[9] + x[14])/3
Group5 <- (x[5] + x[10] + x[15])/3
```

I hope to get the simplify code for this task! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to put them in a matrix and then use `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(matrix(x, ncol=3)) #From @jogo
#[1]  80.66667  39.66667 290.00000 187.00000  89.33333
```

This gives the same 5 numbers as your `Group1`, `Group2`... `Group5`.

Or some other variations :

```
colMeans(matrix(x, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))
rowMeans(matrix(x, nrow = length(x)/3))
colMeans(matrix(x, ncol = length(x)/3, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: `rowMeans(matrix(x, ncol=3))`

Comment: That's what I am looking for! Thanks for the help! :)